# Getting unique random items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Looking for a solution to this problem I have tried to follow several procedures suggested so far on SO but neither worked.

I want to select a random number of random unique items from selected array. In order to do that, I've written the following function, which always returns duplicates instead of unique items:

```
function getRandomItemsCombination(min, max, sourceArray){
    var items = {};
    //var itemsCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var itemsCount = random.integer(min, max);
    //var randomItem = getRandomArrayElement(sourceArray);
    var randomItem;
    var arrIntegers = []
    while(arrIntegers.length < itemsCount){
        var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*(sourceArray.length - 1))
        var found=false;
        for(var i=0;i<arrIntegers.length;i++){
            if(arrIntegers[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
        }
        if(!found)arrIntegers[arrIntegers.length]=randomnumber;
    }

    items.items = [];
    var randomItemsIndex = {};
    items.quantities = [];
    var existing = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++){
        randomItem = sourceArray[arrIntegers[i]];
        var index = randomItemsIndex[randomItem.Long_desc];
        if(index == undefined){
            index = items.items.length;
            randomItemsIndex[randomItem.Long_desc] = index;
            existing = false;
        }
        else {
            existing = true;
        }
        items.items[index] = randomItem;
        existing = false;
    }
    return items;
}
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't return unique items?

Thanks!

Comment: what all you doing there in code?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the min, max, and totalWeight parameters? Based solely on the description your provided, they don't seem to be necessary. (I haven't traced through all the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use underscorejs `sample` function

```
_.sample(list, [n])
```

> Produce a random sample from the list. Pass a number to return n
>   random elements from the list. Otherwise a single random item will be
>   returned.

```
_.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
=> 4

_.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3);
=> [1, 6, 2]
```

http://underscorejs.org/#sample

Comment: I don't think this really explains why his example doesn't select unique elements from the array.

Comment: I success him a very fast and easy way to select unique elements from the array. Why he should write this code?! He wast hist time when this code written before..

Comment: This solution doesn't address the underlying problem, nor does it help the OP with his particular question. He wants to know _why_ his method doesn't work, not _how_ to do it. And unless otherwise specified, all solutions on SO are supposed to be native implementations, not library functions.

Comment: This actually does address the underlying problem. It doesnt necessarily answer the OPs question but my reading of OP's first sentence is that he has tried a couple of solutions and possibly doesnt care how he does it. Either way, this answer certainly has a place here as it may be useful to the next person along, even if it is not selected as the correct answer.